# What are some to-do/reminder + calender apps in Ubuntu that pin to the menu bar indicators?

Tags: unity, appmenu

I want to click on an icon and quickly add an event or a note. Are there any apps like that? By menu bar I mean the top most panel, I want the app to be beside the battery sign.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing Google Calendar Desktop application

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install calendar-indicator
```

Once installed, go to top left corner and click on [image]

and then search for Calendar-indicator and once you are able to see the ICON you can drag to vertical sidebar like this-->[image]

And now you can start making use of it. One can easily sync with the google calendar also to access the schedules anywhere(laptop or smart phone etc...).

This works fine on my Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS.